# In Pokemon Go, how to beat multiple Pokemon in a gym if there are 2, 3, or 8 of them?

Tags: pokemon-go

I have been to some gyms that have 2, 3, or even 7 or 8 Pokemon defending the gym.

Say, even if there are 2 Pokemon, and one is CP 1700, and the other is CP 2000.  My Pokemon is only CP 2200, so it is very difficult to beat them both, because they combine to have a CP of 3700.

If I lose to the second Pokemon and restart the fight, I have to start with Pokemon #1 again... so even if I defeated Pokemon #1, I have to fight both Pokemon again.

And in some situation, I see 3 or even 7 or 8 Pokemon. In this case how can I defeat them all and occupy the gym?

Comment: I don't know what you're doing, but I frequently take down Lv3-4 Gyms populated with 1.5k-2k CP Pokémon with my 1.1k Eeveelution army...

Comment: I even have more of the opposite concerns. I'm reguölary asking my self, how is it even expected to defend gyms at all. You really have not a real choice for doing so.

Comment: Well, if you don't consider the team aspect, and never fought in gyms, then it will seem impossible to beat so many higher CP Pokemon with your own.  However, the fact that you can repeatedly slam into a gym and all it costs are revives and potions means defenses are actually really fragile.

Answer (score 33):

Your goal in a gym battle is not to beat everything in one go.

Your goal is to KO **at least one**.  I'm pretty sure 6 of your Pokemons can defeat one of theirs.

Once you have beaten at least one, it will deduct prestige.  Reduce prestige to 0 and they lose their gym.

You can use this setup heavily to your advantage by setting up your team to be able to handle any defending Pokemon, KO one, run away, heal up, and repeat.  They will still lose prestige, you won't need so many revives, and you can actually beat a heavily defended gym by yourself.

Comment: as Ashvin also answered, is important to go in groups, not to defeat them, but to fill with more than one pokemon

Comment: IMO, the best way to beat a gym by yourself is actually to cheese it.  Prepare a good matchup between your group and the gym's defenders, get into a fight, switch to a good pokemon on your first guy, kill it, then run away.  You take a lot less damage, they lose the prestige for the loss, and you can heal up using potions without needing revives.  There's nothing that requires you to kill everything in one go.  If you can't kill it before they use their Hyperbeam/Hydro Pump/Big Charge attack, you're not in a good matchup and probably shouldn't keep going.

Comment: If you go in groups, but have a poor matchup, say you guys all use Electric vs a Snorlax with Earthquake, that Snorlax is going to kill every pokemon at the same time.  It can probably wipe out all your team's pokemon and not go down.

Comment: that is a nice explanation, you should edit you answer to add that. i was saying *after* the match is better to go in groups so you can add more pokemon to defend and not wait to other pass by and say: hey, there is a slot!

Comment: I disagree, it's far better to defeat all of them if you can. The gym will lose a lot more prestige this way. Maybe if there are 10 pokemon then yeah but if theres only 2 or 3 then take them all down.

Comment: @Aequitas that goes without saying... the question and answer are clearly talking about a scenario where you're unable to just straight up defeat the gym on your own

Comment: @JonStory that's not what he said. He said defeat the first one then run away as it only takes potions.

Comment: The bottom line is you can do a lot in a gym battle to turn things in your favor.  There is no iron clad defenses in Pokemon Go.

Comment: Stock up on Potions and Revives if you do this to take out a complete gym.  You will need a lot of them (I've single handedly leveled Instinct gyms in the way this answer states, so I'm somewhat familiar with this heh)

Answer (score 15):

Based on the way you are talking, it sounds like you are fighting with a single Pokémon, in this case, you will never be able to "take" the gym, as it's already claimed for your team. Gyms have two "modes":

---

**Fighting a Gym of an Opposing Team**

When fighting a gym with a different team, you will be asked to select up to 6 Pokémon to battle with. In this case, when one of your Pokémon are defeated, the next in line will jump in, and you will continue the fight.

For every Pokémon you defeat in the gym, you will lower the prestige rating of the gym. Lower it enough, and the lowest ranked Pokémon in the gym will be kicked out. You can continue this until all Pokémon are removed, and the gym is neutralised. At this point, you will be able to claim it by putting one of your own into the gym.

---

**Fighting a Gym beloning to your Own Team**

When you fight a gym belonging to your own team, you are asked to select just a single Pokémon. Using this solitary Pokémon, you will then battle all the trainers in the gym. For each one you defeat, you will raise the Prestige level of the gym by a certain amount.

Once you have raised the prestige level enough, another trainer slot will open up (up to 10 max). At this point you, or another member of your team, will be able to add one of their Pokémon into the gym, further strengthening it to attack.

Because you only have a single Pokémon to increase the strengh of the gym, it is a good tactic to put claim it with the lowest CP Pokémon that will be put in. This will allow everyone to raise the rank further. Additional Pokémon should ideally be added in increasing order of CP.

You will personally only be allowed to add a single Pokémon to each time at a time. So if you wish to have several in a newly claimed gym, you will need to have other members of your team put theirs in too.

Comment: Putting your lowest CP pokemon in a gym is bad advice. You get much less prestige for beating a Pokemon with lower CP while the enemy team doesn't suffer any penalties and can just beat your weak Pokemon over and over (just run after beating it) to take the gym down. You want your strongest so it slows down attackers and so you get more prestige when you help defend the gym. There's also a big bonus to attackers if they can take the whole team down and a weak Pokemon makes that much easier.

Comment: @Doval sorry, I didn't mean put a low CP Pokemon in. I meant put the lowest cp you will be adding first. I.e. If there's a group of 5 of you, whoever has the weakest Pokemon you are putting in should put theirs in first.

Comment: Order of how they are put in doesn't matter.  The fight order is randomized, and the lowest CP gets kicked out first.

Comment: Fight order is not randomized. You start battling the lowest combat power to the highest combat power. Additionally, defeating low-combat power pokemon gives a small amount of prestige when training your gym, but gives a flat 100 to enemies. This can be easily exploited by both parties.

Answer (score 1):

I usually go gym hunting with a couple of friends from the same team. We all use our 6 pokemon each to try and beat the gym and bring its prestige down to zero as Nelson mentioned above. Once we beat the gym we each put one of our pokemon inside.

It's generally hard to beat a gym on your own unless your Pokemon are way stronger and the gyms prestige isnt too high.
Good luck catching them all :D